# Centered DIV inside 100% width creates padding-right? - HTML/ CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm making this layout but and I've set the wrapper (.lfull) inside the 100% div on 1000px, but before I resize my window to 1000px it creates spacing on the right.

When I erase "width: 1000px;" from the wrapper (.lfull) the padding goes away but my content won't be centered  anymore, a way to fix this?

[**DEMO HERE COMPUTER**](http://bit.ly/1l5HIu0) (resize your screen to 1000)
[**Phone screenshot (makes the problem more clear)**](http://cl.ly/image/0Y362l0V1r3M/Screenshot_2014-06-12-21-12-21.png)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. If something is width 100%, it is kind of centered in a way already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue only occurs when the viewport width is less than `1000px`.  Here's a simple solution that I *think* accomplishes what you were shooting for:

```
.lfull {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

This will set the width to 100% when there isn't enough room for the content; however, when there is enough room, it'll stop growing at 1000px and remain centered.

Comment: @1200182 Thank you! Your answer helped me with the padding, I've updated the site. But it caused another error. Everything on my site is based on max 1020px. (I've set .lfull to max 1020.) But when I resize the browser the floats work until 1035px and if you resize after that they get pushed under each other. - http://bit.ly/SDKzgV & http://cl.ly/image/2d0V1W3O0Y1q/Screenshot_2014-06-12-21-46-41.png

Comment: There's no simple solution to that issue.  You could set a `min-width` to force the browser to allow enough space, but then you'll have horizontal scrolling.  This is where you would get into the realm of responsive design with media queries.

Comment: Yeah I'm still learning. After this I'll try to learn coding responsive layouts. ^_^ Thanks for your knowledge though. I truly appreciate your help. :)